# Implementing Or in ER Diagram

Tags: symfony, doctrine, entity-relationship

I have this information to draw an ER Diagram.

An enterprise generates documents, these documents are associated to employees, but there are a lot of types of documents. I just can't get to have the right answer to this er diagram.

My solution would be:

Enterprise 1-M Document
Document M-1 Type of Document

How do I change the attribues of the Document table depending on the type of document? 
What do you think is the best way to solve this?

Do I have to put all of the documents attributes on Type of Document table? And if we're talking about document1, then attributes of document 2 will be null?

Another solution I think is: A document can be a table document 1 with different attributes or a table document 2 with some other attributes or a table document3 with ome other attributes, and so on, but I just don't know how to show this on an ER - Diagram.

I want to solve it the best way I can.

By the way I'm using Doctrine, and Symfony2.

Answer (score 0):

The way i see (and understand) your case :

"An enterprise generates documents, these documents are associated to employees, but there are a lot of types of documents."

**Enterprise** id, name

**Employee** id, first name, last name, enterprise_id (FK to Enterprise.id)

**DocumentType** id, name

**Document** id, content, document_type_id (FK to DocumentType.id)

**SpecificDocument** id (FK to document.id), specificfield1, specificfield2

**SpecificDocument2** id (FK to document.id), specificfield3, specificfield4

**EmployeeDocument** employee_id (FK to Employee.id), document_id (FK to Document.id)

You should be able to generate your ER diagram with this info.

EDIT :

But the best way is to not use an ER DB but a Document DB (ex : MongoDB).

Comment: Yes, that's what I just posted in my question.
But, what about if a type of document has two int and two varchar attributes, but other type of document has 1 boolean and 1 float attribute. They are documents, but they behave like different tables. How do I tell Documents table to be a type of document1 or a type of document2?

Comment: I added SpecificDocument & SpecificDocument2 which both refer to mother class Document (containing generic fields like name, path ...)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like types of documents is a case of specialization.  If you are doing ER modeling, you can use a feature of Extended ER to express specialization directly. Load the following PDF and navigate down to "Specialization"  for the way to diagram specialization.

http://www.sis.pitt.edu/~valeriab/1022-spring08/Chapter6.pdf

If you are designing a relational database to implement your ER model, you need to learn a couple of techniques, namely Class Table Inheritance and Shared Primary Key.  Each of these techniques has a tag here in SO, and dozens of useful answers.